# Macro to copy-paste range in row to different sheets based on specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 3 sheets: first one is the raw data sheet, then 2 target sheets. I would need a macro that would look at cell C in raw data sheet and based on the 2 values (YES or NO), will copy and paste the range A:Y in sheets 2, respectively 3.
Example: if on C2 in raw data sheet i have YES, copy A2:Y2 and paste into sheet 2, same range A2:Y2. If instead i have the value NO, copy A2:Y2 and paste into sheet 3.
Then go to next row and copy-paste A3:Y3 to sheet 2 if YES or A3:Y3 to sheet 3 if NO.

I wrote something that only works for the 2nd row, but i don't know how to make it loop... so basically when it passes to the next rows, it still copies the values from A2:Y2 to the target sheet, instead of copying A3:Y3, A4:Y4 etc..
Pasting my poor code below:

```
Sub IdentifyInfraction()

    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngA = Range("C2", Range("C65536").End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In rngA

        Worksheets("raw_data").Select
        If cell.Value = "YES" Then
            Range("A2:Y2").Copy
            Worksheets("Value_YES").Select
            Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        ElseIf cell.Value = "NO" Then
            Range("A2:Y2").Copy
            Worksheets("Value_NO").Select
            Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Please help!!! :-s

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would just be to replace the number `2` in each of your ranges to a variable which you then increment at the end your statement, before you go to the next cell.

For example:

```
Dim i = 2

Set rngA = Range("C2", Range("C65536").End(xlUp))
For Each cell In rngA

Worksheets("raw_data").Select
If cell.Value = "YES" Then
    Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Value_YES").Select
    Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ElseIf cell.Value = "NO" Then
    Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy
    Worksheets("Value_NO").Select
    Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If
i = i + 1
Next cell
```

So, originally we set `i = 2`, this is to go in line with your starting row of `2` mentioned in your question.  Then, `Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy` is the same as saying `Range("A2:Y2").Copy` or `Range("A3:Y3").Copy`, etc.

This will go through any copy each row, a new row each time, and paste it to the respective row in the various sheets.

I hope this works for what you are trying to do, if not let me know.

---

There are a few things I'd also recommend looking into.  There's a much better way to copy and paste, without going back and forward through the sheets.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw_data").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Value_YES").Range("A" & i)`

Something like this would take the whole row from `raw_data` and transfer it to `Value_YES`.  You'd have to mess around with it and change the range from `Rows(i)`, but that's just an example.

I'd also recommend that you look into [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to better understand why it's frowned upon to use Select and Activate in Excel VBA.

Comment: Remove the Dim should work, This code needs to paste in the next available cell, as it stands, it would only paste in row "i"

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
Sub GetR_Done()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, LstRw As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Nr As Long, Yr As Long
    Dim Ys As Worksheet, Ns As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("raw_data")
    Set Ys = Sheets("Value_YES")
    Set Ns = Sheets("Value_NO")

    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & LstRw)
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c = "YES" Then
                With Ys
                    Yr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, "A"), .Cells(c.Row, "Y")).Copy Ys.Range("A" & Yr)

            End If

            If c = "NO" Then
                With Ns
                    Nr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, "A"), .Cells(c.Row, "Y")).Copy Ns.Range("A" & Nr)

            End If

        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you really require to paste values, then use this one

```
Sub GetR_Done()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, LstRw As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Nr As Long, Yr As Long
    Dim Ys As Worksheet, Ns As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("raw_data")
    Set Ys = Sheets("Value_YES")
    Set Ns = Sheets("Value_NO")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & LstRw)
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c = "YES" Then
                With Ys
                    Yr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, "A"), .Cells(c.Row, "Y")).Copy
                Ys.Range("A" & Yr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            End If

            If c = "NO" Then
                With Ns
                    Nr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End With
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, "A"), .Cells(c.Row, "Y")).Copy
                Ns.Range("A" & Nr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            End If

        Next c
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub IdentifyInfraction()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("raw_data") 'reference "raw data" sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("C2", .cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) ' loop through referenced sheet column C cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            Worksheets("Value_" & cell.Value).Range(cell.Address).Resize(, 25).Value = cell.Resize(, 25).Value 'have proper target sheet A:Y current cell row values as "raw data" sheet ones
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```